# php pdo mssql prepared statement

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm having trouble on using a pdo based function

my `GetCurrentLanguage()` function returns an int of 0 or 1

```
public function GetCurrentLangName()
{
    $stmt = $GLOBALS['website']->prepare("SELECT * FROM available_languages WHERE id = :id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $this->GetCurrentLanguage(), PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $stmt->execute();
    $fetch = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $fetch['name'];
}
```

and is not working, it returns

> Notice: Undefined index: name

Comment: You could either [check the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) or `var_dump($fetch)` to see what happen...in your case, `fetchAll` returns all rowS as an array, so it's an array of array. You might need to use `$fetch[0]['name']` (if you're sure at least one row will be returned, of course).

Answer (score 2):

If you're expecting many rows, you could have just loop it.

```
public function GetCurrentLangName()
{
    $data = array():
    $stmt = $GLOBALS['website']->prepare("SELECT * FROM available_languages WHERE id = :id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $this->GetCurrentLanguage(), PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $stmt->execute();
    $fetch = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($fetch as $row) {
        $data[] = $row['name'];
    }
    return $data;
}
```

This function (`->fetchAll()`) returns a multi-dimentional array. May look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => lang
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => lang
        )
)
```

Could have used `print_r()/var_dump()` on `$fetch` and you'll see what it yielded.

Comment: it returns the string "Array"

Comment: @user3811098 yes thats it! because its not a string! its an array, use `print_r()` and you'll see!

Comment: well ty, but it seems to return Array ( ) 1, maybe something wrong with my database connection? how can i check for errors?

Comment: @user3811098 there can be myriad of things, maybe there isn't really a result on that query thats why its empty

Answer (score 0):

you should set parameter as a param you want to bind.

```
public function    GetCurrentLangName($id)
{
    $stmt =     $GLOBALS['website']-    >prepare("SELECT * FROM     available_languages WHERE id = :id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id,     PDO::PARAM_INT);

$stmt->execute();
$fetch = $stmt->fetchAll();
return $fetch['name'];
```

}

Comment: indeed but the parameter is $this->GetCurrentLanguage() , it can't work like that?

edit: tried that way, but the problem perssists

Answer (score 0):

`fetchAll()` returns two dimensional array, so instead of returning `$fetch['name'];` it should be
`return $fetch[0]['name'];` or better use `fetch` to return a single row :

```
$fetch = $stmt->fetch();
return $fetch;
```

then use function like this:

```
$data  = GetCurrentLangName();
$language = $data['name'];
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 for return $fetch[0]['name'];
and an empty result when i just use return $fetch

Comment: Read my answer carefully if you use fetch you dont need to use 0 index. Please read it

Comment: If you use fetchall you will need it so i recommend you to use fetch()